# Concatenate php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am not very good at php. I have a function to check for an empty field and the correctness of email

```
if (empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
}
```

There is also a code in php.blade in which you need to insert this check

```
@php

$split = explode('@', $email);
$first = $split[0];
$second = $split[1];

@endphp
<a href="" data-first="{{ $first }}" data-second="{{ $second }}" class="js-combaine-email"></a>
```

How to do it correctly?

I just pasted into @php and it doesn't work

```
@php

if (empty($email) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
}
 else {
$split = explode('@', $email);
$first = $split[0];
$second = $split[1];
}

@endphp
<a href="" data-first="{{ $first }}" data-second="{{ $second }}" class="js-combaine-email"></a>
```

Comment: what do you want to show when there is no valid email ?

Comment: *"and it doesn't work"* - And _what_ doesn't work? Please explain your problem better; "doesn't work" isn't a good description of the problem. What's your expected outcome? What's your actual outcome? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @TimLewis from first glace he can end up with `undefined $first` if the email is not valid. But you are right, that is not a good way to describe an issue, especialy on stackoverflow.

Comment: @N69S Yeah, I noticed that too; using `{{ $first }}` and `{{ $second }}` when the only time they can be defined is in the `else` condition is a recipe for disastor, but I'm seeing so many questions that simply say "it doesn't work", but not saying **why** it doesn't work. We can guess at the issues (or infer them from the code), but it's better to get the asker to clarify (and maybe teach them to be better issue reporters in the future)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution where you dont show the link if there is no valid email

```
@if(!empty($email) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    @php
        $split = explode('@', $email);
        $first = $split[0];
        $second = $split[1];
    @endphp
<a href="" data-first="{{ $first }}" data-second="{{ $second }}" class="js-combaine-email"></a>
@endif
```

You can also add another @else before the @endif and show a message `"no-email"`